# Swift UIStepper and UITextField inside UITableView text overlapping and unable to syncronize

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uistepper

I need a UITextField and an UIStepper inside a cell and update both when one of two change the value. I reach my goal also using a tableviewcontroller but now I've two problems:

1 - To sync the elements value, I create two arrays that I use to maintain the tag id of each rows. To be sure that all tags are unique, I starting count from 800 for the stepper and from 900 for the text field. The problem is that these values are always duplicated when I add a new row inside the table. As example, if I add a new Row, instead found 802 inside the array, i find 802 and 803 so I'm unable to clearly identify the text assigned to each stepper.

2 - when I update the value through stepper the text on the text field overlap with the previous text like shown in this image:

[image]

This happen only for value added during the UITable creation, if I add a value lately this problem doesn't happen.

I clearly understand that all the problems are related to the cell reuse that Swift do for performance reason, but I can't find a solution. My code is below:

```
    class barcodeInfo: Codable {

    var code = ""
    var quantity = 1

    init(code: String, quantity : Int) {
        self.code = code
        self.quantity = quantity
    }
}


class BarcodeTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var barcodeList = [barcodeInfo]()
    var QuantityMapping = [Int: Int]()
    var currentStepperTag = 900
    var currentQtyTextTag = 800

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 50;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        barcodeList = [barcodeInfo(code:"test", quantity: 4),barcodeInfo(code:"test1", quantity: 10)]
    }


    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        var isBackSpace = Int32()

        if let char = string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
        }
        if (isBackSpace != -92) {
            if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits) == nil {
                return false
            }
        }

        guard let textFieldText = textField.text,
            let rangeOfTextToReplace = Range(range, in: textFieldText) else {
                return false
        }
        let substringToReplace = textFieldText[rangeOfTextToReplace]
        let count = textFieldText.count - substringToReplace.count + string.count
        return count <= 5
    }



    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        print(barcodeList.count)
        return barcodeList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let currentBarcode = barcodeList[indexPath.row]
        print(currentBarcode)

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "barcodeCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        // cell.allowsSelection = false
        cell.textLabel?.text = currentBarcode.code

        let customStepper = UIStepper (frame:CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width - 225 , y: 5, width: 100, height: 20))
        //let customStepper = UIStepper()
        customStepper.autorepeat = true
        // Add a function handler to be called when UIStepper value changes
        customStepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        customStepper.tag = currentStepperTag
        customStepper.maximumValue = 99999
        customStepper.minimumValue = 1
        customStepper.wraps = false
        customStepper.value = Double(currentBarcode.quantity)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(customStepper)

        customStepper.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customStepper.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        customStepper.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 94).isActive = true
        customStepper.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 29).isActive = true
        customStepper.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.rightAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true

        let quantityTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width - 300, y: 5, width: 50, height: 20))

        //let quantityTextField = UITextField()
        quantityTextField.delegate = self
        quantityTextField.smartInsertDeleteType = UITextSmartInsertDeleteType.no
        quantityTextField.tag = currentQtyTextTag
        quantityTextField.text = String(Int(customStepper.value))
        cell.contentView.addSubview(quantityTextField)

        quantityTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        quantityTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        quantityTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        quantityTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 21).isActive = true
        quantityTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.rightAnchor, constant: -125).isActive = true

        QuantityMapping[currentStepperTag] = currentQtyTextTag
        print("currentQtyTextTag is now \(Int(currentQtyTextTag))")
        print("currentStepperTag is now \(Int(currentStepperTag))")
        currentQtyTextTag += 1
        currentStepperTag += 1

        return cell
    }


    @IBAction private func stepperValueChanged(_ sender:UIStepper!){
        print(QuantityMapping)
        var tagDecrement = 800
        let textTag = QuantityMapping[sender.tag] ?? 0
        if let currentQuantityTextField = self.view.viewWithTag(textTag) as? UITextField {
            currentQuantityTextField.text = String(Int(sender.value))
            if(textTag >= 900){
                                 tagDecrement = 900
                             }
        //let itmIdx = ((textTag - tagDecrement)-2)
          let  itmIdx = 1
                  self.barcodeList[itmIdx].quantity = Int(sender.value)
        }
        print("sender tag: \(Int(sender.tag))")
        print("textTag \(Int(textTag))")
        print("UIStepper is now \(Int(sender.value))")
    }
```

Comment: Consider that each call of `cellForRowAt` – and this method is called very often – adds a new stepper and textfield to a reused cell. It's highly recommended to design the UI as custom prototype cell in Interface Builder.

Comment: For every addSubview in your cell you should either check whether it is there already and just change it but not add it again or always remove the old one before adding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a solution for your textview could be

```
cell.contentview.subviews.map(if $0.isKindOf(UITextView.self) { $0.removeFromSuperview() })
```

then do your addSubview(textView) afterwards

Do this although for your others added subviews - with the right type check of course

Comment: Thank you very much! it's work! just a question, is not a counterproductive delete and recreate all components each time the cell is redraw!? there is a better way to handle this ? like maintain an index and update the cell if exists?

Comment: yes, better it would be if you just change your existing subviews. like this: cell.contentview.subviews.map(if $0.isKindOf(UITextView.self) { $0.text = newText })